# Linking simple products to configurable product via SOAP API V2

Tags: magento

Does anyone know how to link a configurable product to a simple product via the API?

I don't think the Product Link API does this:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/api/catalog_product_link#catalog_product_link.assign

Seems others are having the same issue.. just trying to see if anyone here has a solution:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/75803/

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen any solution outside of custom code to save the objects. There are community modules to accomplish this, as I recall.

Comment: Any module in particular you had in mind? We're looking at using a bulk import module but I would rather just be able to create all the products via the API then link them up