# Magento Associated Product Options

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.4

I have imported all of my products as `configurable` and their options as `simple` product types, all the simple products have the correct size attributes and the configurable products have the right `attribute_set`.

What is the best way of associating the product options with their products?

I would rather not do this with SQL, or manually if I can help it!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand your question, you want to assign simple products to its' configurable parent? 
If so, please look at Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Configurable model. There is method save() which call resource model's method saveProducts($mainProduct, $productIds):

```
Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')
            ->saveProducts($this->getProduct($product), $productIds);
```

Comment: Could you please expand a little on where to put this code in order for `$this` to work correcly? I would like to just create a simple php file with my array of simple productids for each configuarable product

Comment: If it's separate php file, first of all you need to include all magento core libraries and start application Mage::app($mageRunCode, $mageRunType, $mageRunOptions), just like in index.php - to make possible usage Magento core. After that write something like: $configurableProducts = array('1' => array(1, 2, 3), 2=> array(4, 5, 6)); $model = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_type_configurable'); foreach ($configurableProducts as $mainProductId => $childProductsId) {$model->saveProducts($mainProductId, $childProductsId);}

Answer (score 1):

I always thought this wasn't possible using the [SOAP-API](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/api) (as explained e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205727/linking-simple-products-to-configurable-product-via-soap-api-v2)).

But quickly googling has shown that somebody apparently [managed to do this using the SOAP-API](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/15795/P15/#t292328). Here's the relevant code from the forum post:

```
$this->proxy->call($this->session,
    'catalog_product_link.assign',
    array('configurable',
        $newConfigProdId, //This is the product ID of the configurable product
        $createdVariants, //This is an array of product IDs of simple products to associate to the configurable product
        array(ATTR_ID_COLOR, //This is an array of attribute IDs to create as superAttributes for the configurable product.
            ATTR_ID_SIZE //I've defined them as constants...
        )
    )
);
```